# Navigating view using swipe

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, ios4

I am making a weather app with left, right gesture controls. Meaning a user could have multiple cities whose weather they want to check by swiping left/right on the screen. See screenshots of a sample app that I would like to mimic behavior of.

[image]

[image]

I have two questions.

1. How in the world are they showing the transition between two views in the second screenshot? I tried to replicate the same behavior in Xcode - storyboard. I created two view controllers, one with red background and other with green. I dragged and dropped swipe gesture recognizers on the red one and related the gesture to view controller to the other one using Modal. But only default transitions I see are flip horizontal/vertical,  cross dissolve, partial curl. Nothing like what they have going on. So how are they doing that? Changing to Push doesn't do anything.
2. If I use storyboard then I am limiting the cities user can enter. Meaning if I have two view controllers then view controller 1 will show weather for city 1, view controller 2 will show weather for city 2. Basically swipes are limited to how many controllers I have defined. (one for each city). Is there a way I can make this dynamic? Users can have N-number of cities and N-number of swipes. Similar behavior to weather app that comes built in with every iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are letting the user enter their own cities, you should only create one `UIViewController`that handles a single city. Then you just need to create a `UIScrollView` with paging enabled ([here's a tutorial](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html)) and then hide the page scroll indicator like Solar does. Create several instances of you `UIViewController` and add their views to your `UIScrollView`.

Solar fades in the view of the controller that is becoming visible while fading out the one that is being hidden. This is done using the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods, that allow you to know when the scroll view is being dragged.